# How to add a parent node to the tree hieararchy?

Tags: php

How do you add a parent node to the tree hierarchy? Because here in the code it gets all the childs, but it skips the parent:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Comment: does children have a getParent function?

Comment: this feels unclear to me I could be wrong?

Comment: @treyBake i want to add the parent in context of this function is that possible at all?

Comment: but parent of what? how is the parent defined?

Comment: @treyBake the first time the function is called it has the $parentId, so this is the id of the parent itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0, $isFirst = true) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id'], false);
            if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    if($isFirst) {
        $elements[$parentId]['children'] = $branch;
          $branch = [];
          $branch[$parentId] = $elements[$parentId];
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

passing this

```
{
    "1": {
        "parent_id" : "0",
        "id": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "parent_id" : "1",
        "id": "2"
    },
    "3": {
        "parent_id" : "1",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "4": {
        "parent_id" : "3",
        "id": "4"
    }
 }
```

will produce

```
{
    "1":{
       "parent_id":1,
       "id":2,
       "children":{
          "2":{
             "parent_id":1,
             "id":2
          },
          "3":{
             "parent_id":1,
             "id":3,
             "children":{
                "4":{
                   "parent_id":3,
                   "id":4
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: nice job buzzzz